# org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'body' not found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, apache-tiles

### **-my stack trace**

```
org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'header' not found.
    org.apache.tiles.template.DefaultAttributeResolver.computeAttribute(DefaultAttributeResolver.java:49)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.resolveAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:187)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.start(InsertAttributeModel.java:107)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:306)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(layout_jsp.java:142)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)

**Note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

home.jsp contains :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<head>
  <%--  <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title> --%>
</head>

<body>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to add tiles in my spring application but I'm getting `org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'body' not found`.

Below I mentioned my `tiles.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" 
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <!-- definition name="base.definition" 
       template="/WEB-INF/layouts/classic.jsp">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/basefragments/header.jsp" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />  

  </definition>   -->
 <!-- Home Page -->
  <definition name="base.definition"   template="/WEB-INF/pages/temp.jsp" >  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />  
   </definition>  
</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: Add temp.jsp code to your question.

Comment: i added my temp.jsp above steffen harbich

Comment: oh my god still i am getting this isssue please any one help me

Comment: looks OK so far, provide the stack trace please.

Comment: hi steffen Harbich above i mentioned stack trace

Comment: Your stack trace shows a different error message than your original exception message. Which one is occurring? According to the new stack trace "header" is not found. Is it still commented out in your tiles.xml? If so, try remove the whole comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you,

In your tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definitions" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/classic.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/basefragments/header.jsp"/>  
   <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/page/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="/login" extends="base.definitions">
   <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" /> 
   <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />
   <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/error.jsp" /> 
</definition>
```

where `name="/login"` is url pattern (the container uses a simple procedure for matching the `URL` in the request with a url-pattern in the `web.xml`) u want to map with in Spring `@Controller`

like this

```
@Controller
public class Test{

@RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(){
    return "/login";
}
}
```

for your `<title>`

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" />
```

Comment: i have one doubt you please clear that . in definition tag we using name attribute  right  what is that

Comment: now i am  didn't get exception but that tiles not load in that page

Comment: @R.Anandan you are just assembling the page fragment, you are not requesting for the page via controller because I dont think you've coded for Controller like i mentioned in my answer

Comment: see this is my controller   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String loginPage(Model model ) {
          
         return "login";
     }

Comment: my tile.xml  <definition name="/login" extends="base.definition">
  <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" />
  <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/error.jsp" />
 </definition>

Comment: @R.Anandan first off No `<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />`  inside your definition tag and second you're missing out return "/login"; i have updated my answer.

Comment: i am using ignore="true" in insert attribute thats why its not showing a exception  if i removing ignore="true" again i am getting a exception Nosuch attribute defined